What is wrong with the scroll event behaviour
I'm trying to make one page scroll, in response on mouse scroll. But there is some unknown behaviour. There should be infinite scroll, but it stops from time to time. And sometimes do not react at all. Can somebody tell me what is the problem?


let ay = 1;
let vy = 5;
let scrollStarted = false;
let step = () => {
  // vy += ay;  
  scrollStarted = true;
  window.scrollBy(0, 5);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step)
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', (event)=>{
  if (!scrollStarted) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step)
  }
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Infinite scroll requires you to keep adding things to the DOM. Otherwise, scrolling will stop when you reach the end of the document.

Aside: .bind() has been deprecated. .on() has been the preferred generic event binding method for many years.
